# How do I make a curve with multiple parts, all connected parametrically?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves, mathematics

I'm looking to model the nozzle for a rocket engine in Blender to use in an animation, and I want to be as accurate as I can. This means using math (and a lot of it) to make the model. My problem is, I can't find anything on this type of equation or on parametric curves in modeling.

The math for the nozzle uses 2 arcs and a quadratic bezier, connected at some very specific points. I have no idea where to start, but I'd prefer if I could just put in variables and use math (which I have ready) to define things like the centers of the arcs and the points of the bezier.

Point is, is it possible to do this in Blender, or do I have to pay for other software like Fusion360?

Comment: if you have the formula and you have python knowledge - you can do it. e.g. with Sverchok

Comment: This can be done in blender. Don’t worry. However, Bezier is an approximation, so use a path or mesh (plot the formula directly with Python), or a nurbs curve (know how nurbs math works and use it) instead.